# Why are stylesheets being loaded multiple times on my website?

Tags: javascript, css, cloudflare

Here is a screenshot
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.4/united/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css?v=3">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Russo+One">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.0/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
```

I am not including these files anywhere else. I am using cloudflare. JavaScript files load only once. The issue is only with stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I would check:

1. This may be an issue with the tool you are using to view network
   traffic, not the actual webpage. Try an alternative tool such as
   FireBug. To view the naked HTTP requests use Fiddler2.
2. Does your webpage use Frame/IFrame? If so, each frame is will make
   an independent set of HTTP requests.

To remove all doubt, I would personally restart your computer. The number of times I see 'weird' tool behaviour that vanishes on a restart is astonishing.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare wouldn't be adding additional stylesheets to your site. It looks like those resources are coming via Google and MaxCDN.